# Why systemd-journald is creating '/var/log/journal/machine_id" directory when Storage=auto

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-journald

I was looking into the code of systemd-journald and found this (in `system_journal_open()`):

```c
if (!s->system_journal &&
    IN_SET(s->storage, STORAGE_PERSISTENT, STORAGE_AUTO) &&
    (flush_requested || flushed_flag_is_set())) {

        /* If in auto mode: first try to create the machine
         * path, but not the prefix.
         *
         * If in persistent mode: create /var/log/journal and
         * the machine path */

        if (s->storage == STORAGE_PERSISTENT)
                (void) mkdir_p("/var/log/journal/", 0755);

        (void) mkdir(s->system_storage.path, 0755);

        fn = strjoina(s->system_storage.path, "/system.journal");
```

Here, `system_storage.path` is set to `strjoin("/var/log/journal/", SERVER_MACHINE_ID(s));` in previous function call.

As far as I understood its saying to create `/var/log/journal` directory when storage is set to `persistent`.
But in either of the cases (`persistent` or `auto`) why is it creating `/var/log/journal/machine_id` directory (`(void) mkdir(s->system_storage.path, 0755);`)?
`auto` will store logs persistently if `/var/log/journal` is created beforehand or else logs will be written in `/run/log/journal`.
For `auto` it should not create `/var/log/journal/machine_id` directory right?

Also after reading the comment, how is it possible to create `/var/log/journal/machine_id` without creating the prefix? I am assuming `/var/log/journal` is the prefix.

Comment: I suspect `system_storage.path` is also set depending on persistence.  `systemd` will not create `/var/log/journal` if `Storage=volatile`, `Storage=none`, or `Storage=auto` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`.  This is the documented behavior in `man journald.conf`, and the observed behaviour when I test it.  If this is not the behaviour you expect when reading sources, then there is probably something subtle in the source code you missed (that's very easy to do).  Look at documented behaviour to figure out what programs do, not source code.  If it's not documented, it could be a bug or change.

Comment: Hi Stewart, I have figured it out, it was just a confusion, so if set to 'persistent' the code will create '/var/log/journal' prefix and then machine_id dir, if set to 'auto' then '/var/log/journal' (prefix) is not created hence attempt to create complete path via (void) mkdir(s->system_storage.path, 0755);  will simply fail because 'journal' directory is missing (assuming that most systems already have /var/log/ ) and mkdir command will fail if any of the directories is missing in the complete path (unlike mkdir -p which creates missing dirs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, it was just a confusion, so if set to `persistent` the code will create `/var/log/journal` prefix and then `machine_id` dir, if set to `auto` then `/var/log/journal` (prefix) is not created hence attempt to create complete path via `(void) mkdir(s->system_storage.path, 0755);`  will simply fail because `journal` directory is missing (assuming that most systems already have `/var/log/`) and `mkdir` command will fail if any of the directories is missing in the complete path (unlike `mkdir` -p which creates missing dirs)